# Extracting information from lines having columns occuring more than once

Tags: awk, duplicates

I have a file :

```
chr1 1234 2345 EG1234:E1
chr1 2350 2673 EG1234:E2
chr1 2673 2700 EG1234:E2
chr1 2700 2780 EG1234:E2
chr2 5672 5700 EG2345:E1
chr2 5705 5890 EG2345:E2
chr2 6000 6010 EG2345:E3
chr2 6010 6020 EG2345:E3
```

As you can see there is a specific ID before ':' and there is an id that is repeated after ':' which might be common to more than one row , I want an output that looks something like this:

```
chr1 1234 2345 EG1234:E1 (output as it is since it doesn't have duplicate id in the next row)
chr1 2350 2780 EG1234:E2 (since duplicate the 1st and 2nd column of 1st occurrence & 
3rd and 4 th column of the last occurence) 
similarly
  chr2 5672 5700 EG2345:E1
  chr2 5705 5890 EG2345:E2
  chr2 6000 6020 EG2345:E3
```

I was trying to use a key to move to next column but I am not quiet sure as to how would I extract the column wise values

```
 awk '{key=$4; if (!(key in data)) c[++n]=key; data[key]=$0} END{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print data[c[i]]}' file1
```

In short I want to extract the first two columns of first occurrence and last two columns from the last occurrence of any rows with duplicate 4 th column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one only messes up the record order:

```
($1 FS $4 in a) {                            # combination of $1 and $4 is the key
    split(a[$1 FS $4],b)                     # split to get the old $2
    a[$1 FS $4]=b[1] FS b[2] FS $3 FS b[4]   # update $3
    next
}
{
    a[$1 FS $4]=$0                           # new key found
}
END {
    for(i in a)                              # print them all
        print a[i]
}
```

Test it:

```
$ awk -f foo.awk foo.txt
chr1 EG1234:E2 2350 2780
chr2 EG2345:E1 5672 5700
chr2 EG2345:E2 5705 5890
chr2 EG2345:E3 6000 6020
chr1 EG1234:E1 1234 2345
```

One-liner:

```
$ awk '($1 FS $4 in a) {split(a[$1 FS $4],b); a[$1 FS $4]=b[1] FS b[2] FS $3 FS b[4]; next} {a[$1 FS $4]=$0} END {for(i in a) print a[i]}' foo.txt
```

Comment: I am having problem writing it on single line, how can I do that?

Comment: I writing something like   awk '{ ($1 FS $4 in a); { split(a[$1 FS $4],b) a[$1 FS $4]=b[1] FS b[2] FS $3 FS b[4] ; next }{ a[$1 FS $4]=$0 } END { for(i in a) print a[i] } }' foo.txt and it is giving me a syntax error at END

Comment: I'll add one-liner to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, considering the `key1:key2` as a unique combination and if applying it to filter duplicates. Here `$4` represents the `key1:key2` from your file.

```
awk '!seen[$4]++' file

chr1 1234 2345 EG1234:E1
chr1 2350 2673 EG1234:E2
chr2 5672 5700 EG2345:E1
chr2 5705 5890 EG2345:E2
chr2 6000 6010 EG2345:E3
```

The logic is straight forward, the line identified by `key1:key2` is printed only if it is not seen already.

Comment: I think my explanation wasn't clear enough, I want to extract the first two columns of first occurrence and last two columns from the last occurrence of any rows with duplicate 4 th column

Comment: @AishwaryaKulkarni: Please update your expected o/p in your question.